# MongoDB / C# Driver in Unity causes memory leak

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I'm trying to use MongoDB c# driver (2.18 and 2.22 were tested) in Unity (2022.3.10f1), but creating connection causes memory leak.

I put this code in empty Unity project in Awake function:

```
MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
clientSettings.ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5d);
clientSettings.ServerSelectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5d);
_mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientSettings);

_mongoDatabase = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");
_mongoDatabase.RunCommand((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}");
```

The same code put in default console project in Rider doesn't leak at all while using exact same driver in both projects (same dlls). Unity project without db connection doesn't leak as well.

memory usage for unity project (pretty similar on Windows and Linux (about 10MB per day)):[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpzmQ.png)

Driver was compiled for netstandard2.0

**UPDATE:**

Also amount of connections, read/write requests and so on doesn't matter it always leaks with the same speed

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using Mongo in a game project? Generally you wouldn't want a direct connection to your database from a client due to the inherent security problems of having your connection string/credentials on the client.

Comment: How are you confirming that you're seeing a memory leak?

Comment: do not post links, use plain text instead

Comment: @dododo I linked graph that shows linear growth of memory usage (it's about 10MB per day) while Unity Project without db goes straight

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I'm connecting to database from game server, not directly from client

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I left game server for couple weeks and memory was never released. (one day machine even got stuck because it ran out of memory). Also I used unity memory profiler, and it shows "unknown" memory usage. so these are not C# objects that will be garbage collected. And this code actually do nothing but creating connection, so it looks strage that its constantly allocates memory

Comment: Why is your game server a Unity game?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama It's not a game it's just convenient to use same API, unity network libraries and so on. (and unity provides "Dedicated Server Build", so this is not "wrong usage" of unity)

Comment: OK. I see. In my projects, I use dependency injection. I have IMongoClient registered as singleton, IMongoDatabase as request-scoped (it's an ASP.NET Core project), and then resolve any collections from IMongoDatabase as I need to. I don't see any memory leaks, despite thousands of active users across multiple instances of the server. With the limited example you've provided, it's not really possible to say where you might be leaking memory.  It does seem to be unlikely to be Mongo though.

Comment: Check that there is no managed object leaks. "Unknown" usually means "unmanaged", and it is possible for managed objects to own unmanaged memory. Also ensure you are disposing everything that is disposable. Well designed classes should have a finalizer that ensures native resources are *eventually* released, even if not disposed. But it should not be relied upon, and not all classes are well designed.

Comment: @JonasH thank you for suggestions, but it definitely not this case. This code above is everything I put in empty Unity project. I actually do nothing but creating connection, so there is nothing to dispose. I assume there is something wrong inside Unity (because same code outside of it doesn’t cause any leak)